# Inverse of Next Siblings Selector

Tags: jquery, sizzle

So I came across the [Next Sibling Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) on the jQuery docs today:

```
$("label + input")
```

And was wondering - is there an inverse of this selector? i.e. select the Previous Sibling?

I could use:

```
$("label + input").prev()
```

For example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/AHnSF/), I get all labels in which a label is followed by an input, which is what I want, but is this the only way to do it?

Comment: I think it is the simplest one

Comment: label + input selects all the input immediate next to a label. The prev() selects the label preceding an input. Can you please tell me what exactly you are looking at?

Comment: @RupamDatta See edit, I want a list of all labels, but only those followed by an input. I assumed that since there was a selector for the forward lookup, there may be one for the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array provided by sibling()

Check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/